# Cannot prepare statement for INSERT .. sqlite3

Tags: java, sqlite, prepared-statement

I cannot find why this will not work .. every example i find online uses this construction for preparing the sql string that gets passed to a prepared statement ... but when i do the same the question marks after the VALUE item all appear RED, and when i look at the string in debug mode the placemarkers are empty????

Intellij says that they might be 'invalid tokens'???

It must be something simple  .. but i cannot work it out!!

Thanks

```
public void save() throws SQLException {
    final String sql = "INSERT INTO  tblDay  (PK_DayId, Day, Quota, WeekNo, Note) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try(Connection conn = DbHelper.getConnection(); PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pstmt.setString(1, id);
        pstmt.setString(2, day);
        pstmt.setInt(3, quota);
        pstmt.setInt(4, weekno);
        pstmt.setString(5, note);
        pstmt.execute();

    }
}
```

Comment: Normal characters inside a string literal should not appear in red. Might be some obscure Unicode characters involved, so try typing the text, not copy/paste from elsewhere.

Comment: the string placeholders are always empty, the values get sent separately and are stored somewhere inside the prepared statement object.